# When does trace(A'A) become less than trace(A'DA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, trace

Let A be an $a\times b$ real matrix where $ b \leq a$. The $b \times b$ matrix $D$ is a real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix. The matrix $D$ may not be invertible. Then under what condition $trace(A'A)$ can be less than $trace(A'DA)$? (Or the conditions that lead $trace(A'A)$ to be smaller than $trace(A'D'DA)$ are okay too.)

Any reference, comments or answers are appreciated.

PS. There's no restriction on the eigenvalues of $D$, other than it's real and not negative. Some eigenvalues of D can be zero, or very close to zero, or smaller than one. But the sum of eigenvalues of D (or the trace of D equivalently) is larger than $a$, which is the sum of eigenvalues (or trace) of $I_a$.

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense without a bit more information. However, it might be helpful for you to note that
$$
\operatorname{trace}(A'A) - \operatorname{trace}(A'DA) = \operatorname{trace}(A'[I - D]A]).
$$
So, a *necessary* (but not sufficient) condition is that $I - D$ must fail to be positive semidefinite, or equivalently $D$ must have an eigenvalue greater than $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the point. I want to add that some eigenvalues of [I-D] may not be positive. So some eigenvalues of D can be smaller than 1.

Comment: Another potentially helpful perspective is that if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are the columns of $A$, then $\operatorname{traace}(A'[I-D]A) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^T[I-D]a_i$. If $I - D$ has both positive and negative eigenvalues, then for a column vector $a^T[I - D]a$ could be any real numbers, and your question amounts to asking "when is the sum of $n$ real numbers negative?" which doesn't seems like a question that has an enlightening answer.

Comment: Yes, that's a good point... It's too broad. But I forgot to mention the condition that the SUM of eigenvalues of D (or the trace of D equivalently) is larger than $a$, which is the sum of eigenvalues (or trace) of $I_a$.

Comment: Ok, so we know that $I-D$ is a symmetric matrix with negative trace. Still, that's not much to go on. Are there any restrictions on the matrix $A$?

Comment: The trace of $A$ is smaller than $I_a$ or $D$. Is there any case that the fact that $trace(A)$ bigger than $trace(I_a)$ help? Or can the equation of $trace(A'[I-D]A)$ in terms of the summation of all the elements you presented in the previous comments, be represented as summation of some eigenvalues of [I-D]?

Comment: If $A$ is $a \times b$ (with the possibility of $a \neq b$), then what do you mean by the trace of $A$?

Comment: Sorry, trace(A'A).